# Compile program in linux using c code

Tags: c, linux, exec

I'm trying to write a program that compiles a program in a given directory, and I'm having a couple of questions.

I'm using the command `execv` (and tried other of the exec family).
So when I use this command with a path does  it run it from the code directory+path or only from path <>
for example : my program is in the desktop : `exe.c` . when I use the command `execv` with `"./Users"` path will it go to `"Desktop/Users"`?

The second question is

> How to compile a program through c code?

Thank you!

Comment: `Is how to compile a program through c code.` what you mean by compile using `c` code? compiler is for you no need to re-write your compiler.simply use `gcc -o exe exe.c`

Comment: A program can be compiled using `makefile`. I guess this is what you were trying to ask

Comment: have you tried execv with gcc ??

Comment: @Vikram That's completely not true. Makefile doesn't compile anything itself.

Comment: @BennoZeeman Yes, I meant `makefile` is one of the ways to do it and you have to write makefile accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the exec function for compiling that.

```
 execl("/usr/bin/gcc or cc","cc","path name or filename",NULL);
```

Using this one you can compile that program easily. If the file name is given it will taken from the current directory. Or else it will taken from the given path.

Comment: Thank you, it works!
Someone dwon voted my question so i cant vote up your answer.
only accept it.

Comment: @asdsd Don't mention!!!!

Comment: Please do not call the compiler as `gcc`, this is not portable. Use `execlp()` with `cc` or `c99` as the compiler name.

Comment: Do you know what i need to write to compile the program in a certain directory?

Comment: Really thank you! But another little question, why does the prgram stops after this command?

Comment: @asdsd Because the exec takes the memory of our main program. After this compiler will not came to calling function. To avoid this you can use the fork, inside the child you can call the exec. That time after that execution of exec, our main program start to execute.